# Monitoring 100+ services

Tags: cron, monitoring

I have got a lightweight service like 2MB binary, that runs on user units but I have running like 120 similar services but using a slightly different config on each service.

I would like to monitor all of these services are alert via an API endpoint if any of them goes down.

So far I’ve put together a bash script which iterates through a list (one line one service name) and I am using

```
systemctl status name.service
```

to `grep` and `awk` the status of the service and service name. Lastly, I have an `if` condition inside this `while` loop that curls a post to the API endpoint in case one of the services is not active (running).

I plan to cron this script every minute.  However I am little concerned and had the following questions:

1. Is the every minute cron overkill?
2. What should I look out for in such script/crontab?
3. Is there a better way of doing this? To me this seems a bit amateurish but it was a quick way to get something going.

I am just worried that something will go wrong with the crontab and I might not know until it’s too late, or something else might break, or even worse the system might crash.

Any thoughts if I have a better path forward here?

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

Given that there are many, MANY free software packages for doing monitoring, this seems an odd way to solve the problem.

There are issues of scale (there's always issues of scale, but with a more appropriate platform these will be several orders of magnitude away). e.g. what happens if each instance takes more than a second to respond. There are issues of functionality - how do you define monitoring windows, how do you notify issues, what about windows where you wnat to monitor but not notify. How do you manage history to measure the effectiveness of interventions?....

Eventually you will be running this on a monitoring platform. The sooner you start the less pain you'll have in future.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a script, and you don't need to poll; systemd already knows how to start something when a unit fails. Read up on the `OnFailure=` directive. You can simply define a oneshot service that, for example, uses curl to call a REST endpoint with the name of the failed unit.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, and you have a choice between using an existing monitoring solution or building something more rudimentary. To decide whether the investment in time and effort is worthwhile, do some market research and figure out if the solution could be generalized to other needs.

Personally and for demonstration purposes, I might go for Prometheus + Grafana + Alert manager, but only because I have prior experience and I am already using those tools.

In short the idea would be to expose an API endpoint *within your application* on a predetermined port (a so-called Prometheus **exporter**). Then a Prometheus instance will connect to the endpoints ("targets") and fetch **metrics** at regular intervals (default is usually 15s).

Embedding an exporter inside your application would be easy if you're using Go or Python. So that depends on the technical stack you are using.

Perhaps you are not interested in metrics right now, although they could be useful later on. But you could use Alert manager to make it so that you receive alerts when an endpoint no longer responds after a certain amount of time or connection attempts. Then it usually means that the device is unreachable, or the endpoint has crashed. Sounds like something you want.

One bonus is that you will have **history** too. So you can trace problems more easily if you know when they occur (to correlate with logs).

It would make sense to use a separate device for monitoring, if your architecture permits it. The idea here is to let an external agent probe for your services (pull). A failing service will not always be able to send a notification (push) and crash gracefully.

*But it would be interesting to know what your services actually do behind the scenes.* To put it differently: define what failure means and what the desired result should look like. Just because a service is responding to HTTP queries does not necessarily mean that it is working like it is supposed to. It may be relying on some functionality like access to the Internet, file access or whatever. That's where metrics could be useful.

As an example, an exporter for a web server would return cumulative and average figures for metrics such as the number of bytes transferred, or the number of pages served. If some numbers drop to zero, you can suspect there is a problem somewhere. After all, the web server could be working just fine but be unreachable because of an upstream network outage, resulting in stagnating metrics.

Having an API endpoint is interesting, but it's even more interesting if it actually gives out some useful information, rather than just say "I'm up".